# How do I validate float values so that nothing but a float can be saved before submitting a form in ruby on rails 4?

Tags: ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-4, activemodel

I need a way to only allow values like:

**Ok:** `23.55, 232.43, 300.34 2.34`

**Not ok:** `23.4, 43.344, 343.454, 230, 34`

I have a regex in my model but it seems to allow me to save values like `200, 344, 23`. I need to restrict things so that I'm only allowed to submit form when values are entered in the format of my Ok list.

**Here is my model:**

```
class Garment
    include ActiveAttr::Model
    #include ActiveModel::Validations
    extend CarrierWave::Mount

    attribute :price

    mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader

    price_regex = /\A(?:[1-9]+[0-9]*|0)(?:\.[0-9]{2})?\z/

    validates :price,       :presence      => true,
                            :numericality  => { :less_than => 301.00, :greater_than => 0.00 },
                            :format        => {
                                                 :with => price_regex,
                                                 :message => "Price must be entered in the correct format e.g. 23.45, 203.43 not 43.3 or 234.5"
                                              }
```

**This is how I save the price entered into the form field:**

```
  def create
      @garment = Garment.new(params[:garment])
      if @garment.valid?
      garment = Parse::Object.new("Garments")
      garment["price"] = params[:garment][:price].to_f
      garment.save

      flash[:success] = "Garment successfully added to store!"
      redirect_to '/adminpanel/show'
    else
      render "new"
    end
  end
```

I thought my regex was fine but I think I may need to tweak it more. I was wondering maybe I could some how check the value for a decimal and if it hasn't got one add one with 2 zeros after it before it is saved.

However I think the easiest most sensible way would be to do something before the actual form is submitted.

Would appreciate some help

Thanks for your help

Comment: If you are allowed to save values that you don't want, it seems as though your regex isn't correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a custom validator rather than a regex?

```
validate :valid_price_format

def valid_price_format
  unless price.split('.')[1].try(:length) == 2
    self.errors.add(:price,  I18n.t('.invalid_format') )
  end
end
```

Edited based on comments.

You can scope your translation if it's looking in the wrong place:

```
I18n.t('en.my.translation.location.invalid_format')
```

or

```
I18n.t('invalid_format', scope: 'en.my.translation.location')
```

Comment: This works but how do I customize the error message? It is ignoring the custom error message I created in config/locales/en.yml

Comment: to add error message remove :invalid_format and add string saying the problem, like "please provide the price with 2 signs after period" or smth like this

Comment: Answer updated to explicitly use a translation string.

Answer (score 2):

Floats have quirks [See Here](http://www.rails-troubles.com/2011/12/ruby-float-quirks.html).

Also `23.4` is a valid `float`. `floats` do not hold onto trailing zeros past the tenths place so `23.40` comes out as `23.4`. You are better off storing prices as integer in cents e.g.

```
def price=(money)
  #to_d returns a BigDecimal you could use to_f if you prefer
  self.price = money.to_d * 100 if money
end
def price
   #to_d returns a BigDecimal you could use to_f if you prefer
   #bu BigDecimal is more accurate in comparisons
  price.to_d / 100 if price
end
def display_price
  #this will retun the price as in $XXXX.XX format as a String
  sprintf("$%0.2f",price.to_f)
end
```

This way when you set it it will automatically convert it to an `Integer` and when using the getter method it will return a `BigDecimal`. Optionally you could leave off `display_price` method and use the helper method `number_to_currency(price)` in your views which will also add in commas and other configurable items. See [number_to_currency](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html#method-i-number_to_currency)

Also if you decide to forgo the above you can store them as decimals with the appropriate format using a migration like

```
add_column :table_name,:price, :decimal, precision: 8, scale: 2
```

Which will store them with 2 decimal places.

**Update** as a note

```
garment["price"] = params[:garment][:price].to_f
```

means that even if the user enters `12.00` it will be passed to save as `12.0` because of what is stated above. So you are assuming all prices do not end with a `0`. Otherwise the next line

```
garment.save
```

Will fail silently and it will not be saved in the manor that you expect.

Also you are on rails 4 but not using `strong_parameters`?

`@garment = Garment.new(params[:garment])`

shouldn't this be

`@garment = Garment.new(garment_params)`

where `garment_params` utilizes a `require` and `permit` statement.

Comment: This is all true. Upvote. However, the OP seems to be trying to detect whether people have entered a value using an incorrect currency format. (2.2 is not valid). As all inputs send strings over the web until parsed, this is possible.

Comment: @AFaderDarkly Thanks for the upvote and I am aware of the OP request. I just thought I would point out that he is making it more complex than necessary. Why does it matter if the user says it costs `12` dollars or `12.00` dollars since either way `12 == 12.0 #=> true`. I don't understand why the format needs to be implied unless it is for viewing purposes in which case there are better solutions. Also I updated my answer becuase based on his implementation `12.00` will become `12.0` no matter what.

Comment: This app is a basically an administration panel for an iOS app. I just wanted to make sure everything was sorted before saving from the admin panel so I wouldn't need to make any changes to the app code. The app is completed and all testing is done so I'd rather not touch it if I don't have to. Also the last time I used rails was version 3. I will have to update this code. Thanks for your input. I'm going to check out your links.

Comment: @LondonGuy pleae take careful note of the fact that with this regex your save call will fail **silently** because of the type conversion.

Comment: My back end is parse.com and not ActiveRecord so won't be able to use part of your example. I've actually removed the regex and using A Fader Darkly's answer. What are your opinions on that? It seems to be working as expected.

Comment: @LondonGuy I have no issue with his answer(actually just +1 it) just be careful with `float`s. I certainly understand not wanting to mess with something that is not "broken", Just be wary if you are using these numbers in arithmetic in your application.

Comment: Marked you up. Those links were helpful.

Answer (score 0):

`/^[1-9]*[0-9]+\.[0-9][0-9]$/` matches the "OK" values and rejects the "Not OK" values.

Share and enjoy.